# Secure Browser Extension API requests

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension, csrf, browser-extension

I can't believe that I'm asking this right now, but I have no idea how solve the following problem:

I have a web app that logs every visited page in a browser for better browser history search. The extension is a chrome extension that needs to make a POST request to my API. Obviously, I need to avoid CSRF issues, i.e. other sites using the user's session to post arbitrary data to his browser history. However, since the extension runs in a different origin as a content-script, I cannot retrieve CSRF tokens, hence I cannot make authenticated POST requests.

EDIT:

So I now know that I can use chrome.storage (and equivalents in other browsers) to store a token that only my content_script can read. However, I still haven't solved the issue of how getting that token into chrome.storage in the first place

I seem to miss something really obvious ...

Comment: You can always set that token upon installation.  Query your servers initially to get the token.  User allows that computer ID to be added to their account.  Done.

Comment: This might sound dumb, but how would I query my server securely? As far as I can see I can't get a CSRF token for that query, and if its CSRF-protected, that anyone could get the user's token?

Comment: 1. Extension queries server, gets a not-yet-activated token.  2. Extension opens up a browser window taking the user to your website to login.  3. User logins in and is prompted to add this new computer to their account.  4.  User enables the computer, effectively enabling the new security token.

Comment: Also, I haven't written a Google Chrome extension in awhile, but have you inspected its HTTP requests?  Are you sure there's no identifying information in it, such as a `Referer` header or something referencing the extension ID?  Something you can use to show that the request came from your extension?

Comment: I will try your proposed solution, but the problem with anything fancy regarding the request is I think ultimately defeated by the fact that anyone could spoof it?

Comment: What I do wonder though is how the "big" guys like Pocket or Evernote do it? This seems like incredibly overengineered. Coz I don't think either extension requires me to approve my computer or anything

Comment: Anyone can spoof anything.  There is nothing you can do about that.  Your goal is to prevent CSRF attacks.  My suggestion takes care of that problem for you.  There are 100 ways to skin this cat.  If you want to see how other extensions do it, watch their HTTP requests.

Comment: Is specific, manual user action the only way to prevent CSRF attacks? Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to just install, and maybe see a post-install message

Comment: I'm sure it's not the only way, just one way. How do you expect to securely add users to an existing account without them logging in though? And, did you inspect those HTTP requests coming from your extension to see if they have the extension ID in then?

Comment: Ok, so I checked the HTTP requests, but no identifying information that could nail the origin to my extension.

Comment: And I thought I would maybe be possible to add users simply based on their session which yes requires them to login. Ideally, it happens automatically though, right? As mentioned, none of the "big" players seem to require such heavy user interaction

Comment: @Brad - is it okay if user can see the session key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I realized that chrome.storage provides a means to sync/pass confidential data like your token that is only accessible to your scripts.

Hence, the solution is to visit a webpage of yours, and have a content script extract the token and store it in chrome.storage.

Comment: How does this strategy compare with using oauth to id your user?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a content script isn't necessary, and you should just be using the [chrome.webNavigation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API from your [event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) to get the user's browsing activity.

You'll still need the user to log into your service somewhere in the browser. If you take your service's origin as a host permission, your extension will be able to [make XHRs as the user](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), which may be enough to solve your XSRF problem, at least as long as nobody else can intercept the user's login cookies.

Comment: I need access to the DOM to convey the webpages content which is why I needed the content_script in the first place. Good to know however that you can make XHRs as the user